# Creating a array of Box2D body

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i have a ball which is a box2d body and moves around the screen... i want to create multiple balls of similar type and they should also collide among them self..

the code i am using now is

```
ballcount = [[levelData objectForKey:@"ballcount"]intValue] ;

ballarray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ballcount]init] ;

for (int j=0; j<ballcount; j++) {
ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png"];
[ballarray insertObject:ball atIndex:j];
[self createBallBoundingBox:(CCSprite *)[ballarray objectAtIndex:j]];
[[ballarray objectAtIndex:j]setPosition:ccp(arc4random() % 480 , arc4random() % 320)];  

[self addChild:[ballarray objectAtIndex:j]];
}
```

There is only one sprite appearing on the screen when i run it ? any suggestions what am i doing wrong ... it works perfectly when only one ball is there

Thanks

ok i have got the above code to work but now i am having a problem with the movement in the tick method .. the box2d shapes are moving but the CCSprite shapes are not getting attached to the box2d bodies here is my code

```
world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {

        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {

            CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();


            if ([sprite isKindOfClass:[Ball class]]) 
            {

                b2Vec2 Vel = b->GetLinearVelocity();
                float32 angle =  atan2(Vel.y, Vel.x);
                angle += -M_PI/2;

                b->SetTransform(b->GetPosition(),angle);

                sprite.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                      b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);

                sprite.rotation  = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());

            }
```

Ok guys here is my createBoundingBox definition

```
-(void)createBallBoundingBox:(Ball *)ballSprite{
b2BodyDef BallBodyDef;
ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
ballBodyDef.position.Set(ballSprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO, ballSprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
ballBodyDef.userData = ballSprite;
ballBody = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);


/// test circle shape on ballbody

b2CircleShape BallCircleShape;

BallCircleShape.m_radius = 10/PTM_RATIO;

// Create shape
/*
b2PolygonShape ballShape;
int num = 7;
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
    b2Vec2(0.0f / PTM_RATIO, 19.2f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-10.7f / PTM_RATIO, 15.2f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-6.7f / PTM_RATIO, -3.2f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-1.7f / PTM_RATIO, -18.0f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(7.7f / PTM_RATIO, 0.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(10.5f / PTM_RATIO, 14.7f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(0.2f / PTM_RATIO, 19.0f / PTM_RATIO)     
};

ballShape.Set(verts,num);
 */
// Create shape definition and add to body

b2FixtureDef ballFixtureDef;
ballFixtureDef.shape = &ballCircleShape;
ballFixtureDef.density = 1.0f;  
ballFixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
ballFixtureDef.restitution = 1.0f;
ballFixture = ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballFixtureDef);

b2Vec2 direction(5,2);
direction.Normalize();
float force = 1.0f;

b2Vec2 position  = ballBody->GetPosition();

//Apply linear velocity 

ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force*direction,ballBody->GetPosition());

b2Vec2 Vel = ballBody->GetLinearVelocity();
float32 angle =  atan2(Vel.y, Vel.x);
angle += -M_PI/2;

ballBody->SetTransform(ballBody->GetPosition(),angle);
```

}

any ideas ? Let me know

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: i didn't found an error yet, but try using "ball" instead of "[ballarray objectAtIndex:j]" three times.

Comment: Ok , i have managed to get array of CCSprite displaying .. my next problem is how to simulate in tick: method ?

Comment: how did you solve the "one ball"-problem? you need to share this with us, such that this is helpful for a future reader ...

Comment: create a temp ccsprite  Mice *tempmice = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Ball.png"];
Then, add the ball at random position                               [tempmice setPosition:ccp(arc4random() % 460 , arc4random() % 300)];
Then add it to the layer                                                                               [self addChild:tempmice];                                                          Then i my function to create a box2d body
[self createMiceBoundingBox:tempmice];
Then i add it to the array
[miceArray addObject:tempmice];

Answer (score 0):

inside your method

```
[self createBallBoundingBox:(CCSprite *)[ballarray objectAtIndex:j]];
//OR NOW
[self createMiceBoundingBox:tempmice];
```

did you forgot to attach the Ball as UserData to your b2Body

```
- (void) createMiceBoundingBox: (Ball*) ball
{
    //...
    b2Body body = ...
    body.SetUserData(ball);
    //..
}
```

if not show us the code of the method

EDIT: if you use Mice instead of Ball make sure you update tick method to

```
if ([sprite isKindOfClass:[Mice class]])
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this line ? (i also found it in tick)
ballBody->SetTransform(ballBody->GetPosition(),angle);

Comment: i want the object to point in the direction of movement so i am calculating the angle of rotation and then rotating the body accordingly ... i am using this code for some other object than the ball so direction is necessary ...

Comment: did you debug or log if sprite.position are changing ?

Comment: yea did that used breakpoints runs fine but only for one object ie: only one Ball object moves with the box2d body the other body moves on its own...

Comment: they move on its own? who move them? and in what way ?

Comment: yea it moves on its own as i have applied initial velocity.the friction is set to 0 so its always moving .. it moves i just random direction ...